# Alexa Skill Not Calling Endpoint Under Certain Conditions

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am developing an Alexa skill and testing it in the Alexa Developer Console. I am having issues with certain questions I ask will trigger no response.  On these occasions, my endpoint is not getting called, or the DefaultFallback intent being fired.

I can re-produce the error and it only happens on certain questions.  The debug log shows the entries below. I have deployed the skill to a device and get the same response (i.e. nothing). The skill remains open as I can continue to ask other questions and get a response.

If I substitute the word 'sausage' for certain words it gives no response, but using a word such as 'free' will return a response.

Run out of ideas about what is going on...

**Event: Text.TextMessage**

```
{
    "event": {
        "header": {
            "namespace": "Text",
            "name": "TextMessage",
            "messageId": "messageId",
            "dialogRequestId": "ba1efffc-b29e-4cef-bcc0-3ceb418b89ec"
        },
        "payload": {
            "textMessage": "do you have any sausage samples"
        }
    },
    "context": [
        {
            "header": {
                "namespace": "System",
                "name": "SettingsState",
                "payloadVersion": "1"
            },
            "payload": {
                "settings": [
                    {
                        "key": "com.amazon.alexa.characteristics.viewport.experiences",
                        "value": "[{\"arcMinuteWidth\":\"246\",\"arcMinuteHeight\":\"144\",\"canRotate\":\"false\",\"canResize\":\"false\"}]"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "com.amazon.alexa.characteristics.viewport.shape",
                        "value": "RECTANGLE"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "com.amazon.alexa.characteristics.viewport.pixelWidth",
                        "value": "1024"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "com.amazon.alexa.characteristics.viewport.pixelHeight",
                        "value": "600"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "com.amazon.alexa.characteristics.viewport.dpi",
                        "value": "160"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "com.amazon.alexa.characteristics.viewport.currentPixelWidth",
                        "value": "1024"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "com.amazon.alexa.characteristics.viewport.currentPixelHeight",
                        "value": "600"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "com.amazon.alexa.characteristics.viewport.touch",
                        "value": "[\"SINGLE\"]"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "header": {
                "namespace": "SpeechSynthesizer",
                "name": "SpeechState"
            },
            "payload": {
                "token": "amzn1.as-ct.v1.ThirdPartySdkSpeechlet#ACRI#ValidatedSpeakDirective_amzn1.ask.skill.8f0abe6c-a5e8-4585-912f-4e21df999811_6bf05e00-bc3a-4b1e-8b40-9664b36c0378",
                "offsetInMilliseconds": 1000,
                "playerActivity": "FINISHED"
            }
        },
        {
            "header": {
                "namespace": "AudioPlayer",
                "name": "PlaybackState"
            },
            "payload": {
                "token": "",
                "offsetInMilliseconds": 0,
                "playerActivity": "IDLE"
            }
        },
        {
            "header": {
                "namespace": "Alerts",
                "name": "AlertsState"
            },
            "payload": {
                "activeAlerts": [],
                "allAlerts": []
            }
        },
        {
            "header": {
                "namespace": "VisualFocusManager",
                "name": "VisualFocusState"
            },
            "payload": {
                "inFocus": {
                    "component": "ListRenderer",
                    "idleTimeInMilliseconds": 0
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "header": {
                "namespace": "AudioFocusManager",
                "name": "AudioFocusState"
            },
            "payload": {
                "dialog": {
                    "component": "SpeechSynthesizer",
                    "idleTimeInMilliseconds": 0
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "header": {
                "namespace": "ListRenderer",
                "name": "RenderedListState"
            },
            "payload": {
                "listToken": "amzn1.as-lt.v1.ThirdPartySdkSpeechlet#LRID#amzn1.ask.skill.8f0abe6c-a5e8-4585-912f-4e21df999811::JTEXd",
                "itemsVisibleOnScreen": [],
                "selectedItems": [],
                "focusedItem": {},
                "renderedItemDetail": {
                    "listItemIdentifier": "amzn1.as-lt.v1.ThirdPartySdkSpeechlet#LRID#amzn1.ask.skill.8f0abe6c-a5e8-4585-912f-4e21df999811::JTEXd",
                    "ordinalNumber": 1
                },
                "highestOrdinalSeen": 1,
                "lastItemOrdinal": 1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Directive: SpeechRecognizer.RequestProcessingCompleted**

```
{
    "header": {
        "namespace": "SpeechRecognizer",
        "name": "RequestProcessingCompleted",
        "messageId": "77057f6b-8f91-4fb4-aab0-c86efc934adc",
        "dialogRequestId": "ba1efffc-b29e-4cef-bcc0-3ceb418b89ec"
    },
    "payload": {}
}
```

**Directive: SkillDebugger.CaptureDebuggingInfo**

```
{
    "header": {
        "namespace": "SkillDebugger",
        "name": "CaptureDebuggingInfo",
        "messageId": "c3175e0f-3c0a-450c-8ef4-5246ce2e1a31"
    },
    "payload": {
        "skillId": null,
        "timestamp": "2019-01-21T10:25:31.211Z",
        "dialogRequestId": "ba1efffc-b29e-4cef-bcc0-3ceb418b89ec",
        "skillRequestId": null,
        "type": "ConsideredIntents",
        "content": {
            "intents": [
                {
                    "name": "General_MobileApp",
                    "confirmationStatus": "NONE",
                    "slots": {
                        "Deliverables": {
                            "name": "Deliverables",
                            "value": "samples",
                            "resolutions": {
                                "resolutionsPerAuthority": [
                                    {
                                        "authority": "amzn1.er-authority.echo-sdk.amzn1.ask.skill.8f0abe6c-a5e8-4585-912f-4e21df999811.MARSHALLS_Deliverables",
                                        "status": {
                                            "code": "ER_SUCCESS_MATCH"
                                        },
                                        "values": [
                                            {
                                                "value": {
                                                    "name": "samples",
                                                    "id": "6ef9161b900632671022358216c7dfe7"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
                        },
                        "Company": {
                            "name": "Company",
                            "value": "you",
                            "resolutions": {
                                "resolutionsPerAuthority": [
                                    {
                                        "authority": "amzn1.er-authority.echo-sdk.amzn1.ask.skill.8f0abe6c-a5e8-4585-912f-4e21df999811.MARSHALLS_Company",
                                        "status": {
                                            "code": "ER_SUCCESS_MATCH"
                                        },
                                        "values": [
                                            {
                                                "value": {
                                                    "name": "Marshalls",
                                                    "id": "abfd923a6acfc93e81ba94b0310b47b2"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
                        },
                        "Media": {
                            "name": "Media",
                            "value": null,
                            "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
                        },
                        "Contact": {
                            "name": "Contact",
                            "value": null,
                            "confirmationStatus": "NONE"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
I now think a certain confidence score is not being met causing the intent not to fire (but not then calling the default fallback intent).  If I ask 'flag laying patterns' the intent fires correctly and I get a full debug trace:-
[image]

If I ask 'flag laying sausages' then I get a small debug trace together with the same considered intent, but no answer and no endpoint call:-
[image]

Comment: Is it possible you're missing the sample utterances in your intents? Can you share the interaction model JSON as well?

Comment: Thanks Milan, From the debug information provided, Alexa was firing a different intent to what I intended, but adding an extra sample utterance has since corrected it.  What I don't understand is why when it was firing the incorrect intent it just seemed to hang rather than call the endpoint for the answer.  Is there some sort of confidence threshold that is not being met perhaps (like DialogFlow has)?

Comment: @MilanCermak I have edited the question a little and added some extra information at the end.  What I think is happening is that Alexa must have an internal confidence score that is not high enough to trigger the call to the intent endpoint, but is enough to have the intent 'considered'.  What I then dont understand is why is the default fallback intent not being fired...

Comment: I'm also not sure about why the fallback intent is not being fired, I don't think I can help you with that. It also depends on how you skill and handlers are configured. Don't look so much at the debug messages you see in the console, but rather focus on the event payload that triggers your skill. It is somewhat different in structure to these console debug messages.